# how to submit flask form data back to the flask route for calculations using python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have speed and time data which is stored in pdf file. from html page I am uploading the pdf file for calculations here is my code

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
application= Flask(__name__)
application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
global df1
application.secret_key = "super secret key"
@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        lines = []
        with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
            pages = pdf.pages
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                for line in text.split('\n'):
                    lines.append(line)
                    print(line)

        df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
        df.drop([0, 1], inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df.astype(str)
        df1= df[0].str.extract(r'(\d*)\ (\d*:\d*:?\d* [AMP ].) (\d*)')
        df1.columns = ["S.No", "Time", "Speed"]
        df2 = df1[df1["Speed"].str.contains("Speed") == False]
        cols = df2.columns.drop('Time')
        df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        fig = px.line(df2, x=df2["Time"], y=df2["Speed"],labels=dict(x="Time", y="Speed"))
        fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)
        print(df2)
        op_col = []
        for i in df2['Speed']:
            op_col.append(i)
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
        x = np.array(op_col)
        x1 = x.astype('int32')
        x2 = x.astype("int32")
        lower_limit = int(request.form.get('lower_limit', 0))
        upper_limit = int(request.form.get('upper_limit', 0))
        def get_count1():
            sub_lists = np.split(x1, np.where(np.diff(x1) < 0)[0] + 1)
            id_count1 = 0
            id_list1 = []
            for unit in sub_lists:
                if min(unit) <= 10 and  max(unit) > 25 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
                    id_count1 += 1
                    id_list1.append(unit)
            return id_count1
            id_count1 = get_count1()
        graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
        return render_template('index.html', graphJSON=graphJSON,shape=df2.shape,count_result1=get_count1(),tables=[df2.to_html()], titles=[''])
    return render_template('index.html')
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
```

in this line

```
if min(unit) <= 10 and  max(unit) > 25 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
```

iam hard coding the min(unit) value and max(unit)instead i want to get from user this two inputs by form input method if user enters those two values it has to give the output result how to do it

```html
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
    <form id="count-form">
      <label for="lower_limit">Lower Limit:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lower_limit" name="lower_limit" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <br>
      <label for="upper_limit1">Upper Limit 1:</label>
      <input type="text" id="upper_limit" name="upper_limit" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <br>
    </form>
```

inplace of 10 it has to the user entered  lower_limit value and inplace of 25 upperlimit it has to take here[image: this is my pdf file structure]